# Get number from EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to get a `float` from an `EditText`'s `getText()` method

This is what I did:

- In layout.xml

> ```
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/et_Amount"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:inputType="number" 
>     android:hint="Units of fuel you purchased">
>
>     <requestFocus />
> </EditText>
> ```

- In my activity

> ```
> public void setAmount() {
>   EditText tx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Amount);
>   float amount = Float.valueOf(tx.getText().toString()); 
> }
> ```

Unfortunately a NumberFormatException is thrown . Any ideas?

Comment: nvm, i got it. It will work if     tx.setText("0");

Answer (score 3):

For real numbers (float or double), use `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`. More about [input types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType).

```
<EditText
       ...
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

To get the value, use something like:

```
EditText amount_text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_Amount);
double amount = Double.parseDouble(amount_text.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem when nothing is there in edit text. Try to check it first.

If edit text have values android:text = "" or "123rt" or "45*" or "asdh", etc. I faced same exception problem.

**EDIT**
This is my suggestion only

```
android:inputType="number"
```

only allows integer values e.g. 20, 30, etc. not float values e.g. 20.002, 30.345, etc.

Use

```
android:numeric="integer|decimal"
```

to allow float values into the edit text by user

Answer (score 1):

The number format exception you are getting is because there is a null value being returned (assuming the value is blank). It doesn't parse a 0 from a null.